# How to post an Image and JSON object with single request to back end Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I want to send image and JSON data to my back end in Spring Boot.
This is my method:

```
@PostMapping
    public void uploadFile(@ModelAttribute FileUploadDto fileUploadDto) {
```

My FileUploadDto  model:

```
public class FileUploadDto {
    private MultipartFile file;
    private CategoryModel category;
```

My CategoryModel  model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Category")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
public class CategoryModel {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    //@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String category_name;
    private String category_description;
    private String image_path;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "category")
    private Set<ProductModel> category;
```

I do not understand where I'm wrong.

My postman request:
[image]

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: This : `Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.dar.darkozmetika.models.CategoryModel' for property`

Comment: Could you also post a sample of your incoming data? I think the problems has something to do with the converting from payload to entity class

Comment: Also, it is a bad practice to convert payload direct into entity classes since entity classes are modified byte code and could cause problems while parsing. Google JPA byte code enhancement for more information

Comment: I save my POSTMAN request. Do you have some example of this problem?

Comment: I see your problem, the payload has to be written in raw and JSON form and not with form-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Your payload has to be raw and in json form. Something like this would help Spring boot to convert your payload into a object of an example class:

```
public class Foo{
     public String foo;
     public String foo1;

     //Getters setters
}
```

And the request handling method:

```
@PostMapping
    public void uploadFile(@RequestBody Foo foo)
```

It is also recommended to parse the payload into some a temporary class and then convert objects of the temporary class into the Entity class and vice versa. Take a look at: https://struberg.wordpress.com/2012/01/08/jpa-enhancement-done-right/ for more information

Also, if you want to upload file per REST I also recommend you to take a look at the following documentation: https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-file-upload-download-rest-api-example/

Best luck.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have one more question. I have a form with image and fields like id, name etc. What do you think, it is better to have 2 requests one for image and one for fields or just one request for all?

Comment: It depends on your server capacity. But I think it is a good practice to do all in one request

Comment: This is my main problem because I can not send image and JSON object. Do you have some example of this? Thet will be very useful for me if you have.